# Apache 2 can't find python packages under Django project directory

Tags: django, python-3.x, apache, docker

I am running Apache2 and Django in a Ubuntu Docker container. Apache can find and is trying to run the Django project but cannot find the python packages contained in under the project directory. It is returning an Import error. See attached picture.

[image: Django error message]

`ImportError at /
Missing required dependencies ['numpy']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8005/
Django Version: 2.1.7
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:

Missing required dependencies ['numpy']
Exception Location: /var/www/html/django_demo_app/INDmain/Lib/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py in <module>, line 19
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.6.7
Python Path:

['/var/www/html/django_demo_app/INDmain',
 '/var/www/html/django_demo_app/INDmain/Lib/site-packages',
 '/var/www/html/django_demo_app/INDmain/Scripts',
 '/usr/lib/python36.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages',
 '/var/www/html/django_demo_app/INDmain',
 '/var/www/html/django_demo_app/INDmain',
 '/var/www/html/django_demo_app/INDmain/main']`

I had the same issue when Apache/Django tried to find the requests package under /var/www/html/django_demo_app/INDmain/main/Lib/site-packages so I added the directory to the path and Apache/Django found the package. Now it is finding the pandas package but cannot find the dependency numpy package located in the same directory. What could be causing Apache and/or Django to fail to see these packages?

Project layout

```
INDmain
--> Include
--> INDmain
--> Lib
--> main
--> Scripts
--> tcl
db.sqlite3
manage.py
```

My configuration/settings files are below. Common settings are not shown for brevity.

Apache .conf file

```
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/html/django_demo_app/INDmain

<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/django_demo_app

    Alias /static "/var/www/html/django_demo_app/INDmain/main/static"

    WSGIDaemonProcess INDmain python-path=/var/www/html/django_demo_app/INDmain:/var/www/html/django_demo_app/INDmain/Lib/site-packages:/var/www/html/django_demo_app/INDmain/Scripts
    WSGIProcessGroup INDmain
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/django_demo_app/INDmain/main/wsgi.py


</VirtualHost>
```

settings.py

```
import sys

sys.path.append('/var/www/html/django_demo_app/INDmain')

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django.contrib.admin',
            'django.contrib.auth',
                'django.contrib.contenttypes',
                    'django.contrib.sessions',
                        'django.contrib.messages',
                            'django.contrib.staticfiles',
                                'main.apps.MainConfig',
                                ]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'INDmain.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'main.wsgi.application'


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        os.path.abspath(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")),
        ]
```

wsgi.py

```
"""WSGI config for INDmain project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/wsgi/"""

import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
import sys

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'INDmain.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()

sys.path.append('/var/www/html/django_demo_app/INDmain')

sys.path.append('/var/www/html/django_demo_app/INDmain/main')
```

Comment: In Django's [deployment docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/), it suggests using `python-home` to specify the virtual env, instead of adding it to `python-path`.

Comment: As an aside, I'd be wary of adding `INDmain` and `INDmain/main` to the python path. It means that some modules will be importable from two separate places (e.g. `main.foo` and `foo`), which can lead to strange behaviour.

Comment: Added the python-path for the daemon mode and now the website just hangs... Does't send a response.   `WSGIDaemonProcess INDmain python-home=/var/www/html/django_demo_app/INDmain python-path=/var/www/html/django_demo_ap
p/INDmain
    WSGIProcessGroup INDmain
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/django_demo_app/INDmain/main/wsgi.py process-group=INDmain`

Comment: @Alasdair I have added the project layout above.

Comment: What is `Lib`, how did you create it? Perhaps you want `python-home=/var/www/html/django_demo_app/INDmain/Lib`.

Comment: @Alasdair Lib was created for a venv that I used in development that resided in the under the project folder. I have made the change to this. `WSGIDaemonProcess INDmain python-path=/var/www/html/django_demo_app/INDmain:/var/www/html/django_demo_app/INDmain/Lib` Removing the python-home attribute keeps the Apache web server from not sending a response. I am now back to it not finding the requests package (first import) in site-packages.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any more specific suggestions. As I said in my first comment, I still think you should be using `python-home` to point to your virtualenv. The only value for `python-home` I've seen you try, `python-home=/var/www/html/django_demo_app/INDmain`, is incorrect, because that is not the virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

So to answer my own question...

I did not want to run this under a virtual environment since the web app is the only thing being run in this Docker container. Therefore, I installed all of the needed python library packages within the base image. My Dockerfile, requirements.txt and Docker compose files are as follows.

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get dist-upgrade -y && apt-get autoremove -y && apt-get autoclean -y
RUN apt-get install -y apt-utils vim curl apache2 apache2-utils
RUN apt-get -y install python3 libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
RUN ln /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
RUN apt-get -y install python3-pip
RUN ln /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/bin/pip
ADD ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ADD ./web_site.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
ADD ./INDmain /var/www/html/INDapp/INDmain
EXPOSE 80 3500
CMD ["apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

requirements.txt

```
django
ptvsd
requests
pandas
openpyxl
xlrd
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2"

services: 
  ind-web-app-ubuntu:
    image: ind-web-app-ubuntu
    container_name: ind-web-app-ubuntu
    ports:
      - '8005:80'
      - '3500:3500'
      - '8006:81'
    restart: always
```

My ending project layout.

```
INDmain
--> INDmain
--> main
db.sqlite3
manage.py
```

My configuration/settings files. Common settings are not shown for brevity.

Apache .conf file

```
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/html/INDapp/INDmain

<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/INDapp

    Alias /static "/var/www/html/INDapp/INDmain/main/static"

    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/INDapp/INDmain/INDmain/wsgi.py

</VirtualHost>
```

settings.py

```
import sys

sys.path.append('/var/www/html/INDapp/INDmain/main')

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
            'django.contrib.contenttypes',
                'django.contrib.sessions',
                    'django.contrib.messages',
                        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
                            'main.apps.MainConfig',
                            ]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'INDmain.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'INDmain.wsgi.application'

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.abspath(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")),
    ]
```

wsgi.py

```
"""WSGI config for INDmain project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/wsgi/"""

import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
import sys

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'INDmain.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Installing the python packages within the existing python environment solved the problem of not finding the python modules in underlying directories for Django and Apache. It took a significant amount of effort to get all of the pieces talking to each other, so hopefully this will help others with similar needs.